# Howto change only the first letter into an uppercase?

Tags: regex, notepad++

If RegEx Find:

```
\b([A-Z])([A-Z]+)\b
```

Replace:

```
$1\L$2
```

`AKU MENCOBA BERUBAH` ---> Result: `Aku Mencoba Berubah`

But how to change only the first character into an uppercase letter?

`aku mencoba berubah` ---> Result: `Aku Mencoba Berubah`

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Is `\U` that difficult to imagine?

Comment: for filtering text only  with RegEx Notepad++

Answer (score 4):

Your regex changes only a bit to

```
\b([a-z])([a-z]+)\b
```

For the replacement string you have several possibilities:

1. make only one character uppercase

   ```
   \u$1$2
   ```

   `\u` has only an impact on the next letter, while `\U` is valid for all following letters
2. Make the second group lower case

   ```
   \U$1\L$2
   ```
3. End the impact of `\U`

   ```
   \U$1\E$2
   ```

The result is in all cases "Aku Mencoba Berubah" for your example.

You can find the [documentation for this replacement strings here](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions#Substitutions).